# Can't find my apache error_log folder

Tags: macos, error, apache, logs

new Mac (Yosemite) and setting up a new dev environment. At the moment cannot find any `error_log` folder at the following paths:

```
/var/log/apache2/error_log
/private/var/log/apache2/error_log
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Any thoughts on where that folder may be?

[image]

Comment: Is apache running at all?

Comment: @patrix I did `sudo apachectl restart` and didn't see anything come up, so tried to check the `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log` and that's where I went down this path of trying to figure out if it's running or not

Comment: Try to connect to the websever at `localhost` and/or run `ps aux|grep http` to see whether apache is running at all.

Comment: Nothing is running at `localhost` or `localhost/app` and this is what I see after running ps: leongaban      10849   0.0  0.0  2432772    672 s006  S+    2:56PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=.cvs --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn http

Comment: No running apache, no error log :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The location of `error_log` is defined in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Run

```
grep '^ErrorLog' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

to see the definition.

Comment: Thanks! yeah it says `/private/var/log/apache2/error_log` which I checked, and there was no error_log folder in there. So I went ahead and made one... fingers crossed

Comment: It's a file, not a folder! Creating a folder with the same name may cause problems, and apache should definitively create the file itself if needed.

Comment: Thx, ok so I removed that folder I made, still no error_log, I guess I have to post a new question about how to run Apache on OSX

Comment: Found the location but no error log in here.